# Detect New Entries in Database Using Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, twitter, bots

I'm currently trying to make a twitter bot that will print out new entries from my database. I'm trying to use python to do this, and can successfully post messages to Twitter. However, whenever a new entry comes in it doesn't update.

How would I go about implementing something like this, and what would I use? I'm not too experienced with this topic area. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: we have no idea what you have in database. But I would remember ID of last used entry and later get entries with bigger IDs, and keep the biggest ID to check it next time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger to propogate the newly inserted rows from the original table to a record table which is under the surveillance of python, and have python post the new record (possibly remove the already posted ones from the record table)

```
DELIMITER //
drop trigger if exists  record_after_insert //
create trigger record_after_insert after  insert on original_table for each row begin
insert record_table (new_record) values (new.new_message);
end //
```